# Writing lognormal function in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to write an inverse lognormal function in python:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.stats as sp
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def lognorm1(x,s,scale):
    ANS = sp.lognorm(s,scale=scale).ppf(x)
    return ANS

curve_fit(lognorm1,x,y)
```

I have no troubles fitting the curve, however the scale paramater is the exponential of what LOGNORM.INV function is on excel. I know I can just log the scale parameter at the end, but is there anyway to rewrite the function so that I don't have to do this everytime?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, [SciPy documentation says](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.lognorm.html)

> A common parametrization for a lognormal random variable Y is in terms of the mean, mu, and standard deviation, sigma, of the unique normally distributed random variable X such that exp(X) = Y. This parametrization corresponds to setting s = sigma and scale = exp(mu).

So let's set it as such:

```
def lognorm1(x, mu, sigma):
    ANS = sp.lognorm(s=sigma, scale=exp(mu)).ppf(x)
    return ANS

curve_fit(lognorm1, x, y)
```

Now the parameters returned by `curve_fit` have the meaning of the mean and standard deviation of the underlying normal distribution.